# Global Arrays value assigning issue

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to assign values to div by a global array (in ascending function) . but the array is always empty in ascending function. Please also mention the best practice in this case.
I wish to set an array in one function , and in the other function I wish to use the same populated array . but after entering all the values I found that page get refresh and the values assign to array and Hidden1 field are set to empty again.

```
        <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var array = new Array();
function get_strings(m)
    {
            i = 1;

            do
            {
            var ArrayElement=prompt("Please Enter a Number");
            i++;

            array.push(ArrayElement);


            }
    while (i <= m);
    document.getElementById('print').InnerHtml = array;
    document.getElementById('Hidden1').value = array;

    };
</script>
<script>
function ascending()
{
    var x = document.getElementById('Hidden1').value;
    document.getElementById('print').InnerHtml = x;
};
</script>


</head>

<body>

<h2>Enter Number of elements</h2>
<br /><br />

<form>
<input id="Hidden1" type="hidden" value="" />
<input id="num" type="text" name="elements"> <br> <input type="submit" value="Submit" text= "Take Input" onclick="get_strings(document.getElementById('num').value)">
<br />


<input type="submit" value="Ascending" text= "Ascending" onclick="ascending()">


</form>

<div id="print"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: InnerHtml = innerHTML. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.innerHTML

Comment: Its because you aren't invoking `get_strings()`. There are a lot of things in your code that are outright against best practices. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: just trying to assign array filled by User input to div id=print

Comment: Well how about some quotes around this, if nothing else? `onclick=get_strings(document.getElementById('num').value);`

Comment: it was working without quotes , but I have putted them. my need s using global array across different function of javascript.

Comment: I eidt the question with updated code

Answer (score 0):

Page got refreshed because you are clicking the submit button, it's just the basic desired behavior when clicking on a submit button. Which brings the question, do you intend to submit this value to the backend? If so what you need to do is to have your backend return the value after the form POST.
If you do not intend on submitting this value, then use a regular button instead of a submit button.